# getOutputStream() has already been called ,but i just use getOutputStream one time in my SpringMVC code

Tags: java, jsp

the process is controller(jump) -> jsp(grid) ->controller(Verification code)
so this is my code
**controller(jump):**

```
/**
 * jump to login in jsp
 * @return
 */
@RequestMapping("/toLogin")
public String toLogin( ) {
    log.debug("to Sign In!---------------------------------------<UserinfoController>");
    return "sign-in";
}
```

**jsp(there is no tag like this "<% ... %>"):**

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="code">验证码</label>
                        <input id="code" type="text" name="code" class="span3 form-control ">
                        <a>
                            <img alt="刷新验证码" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/code">
                        </a>
                    </div>
```

**controller(Verification code):**

```
    OutputStream os = resp.getOutputStream();  
    ImageIO.write(buffImg, "jpeg", os);
    os.close();
```

error is :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getOutputStream(Response.java:644)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getOutputStream(ResponseFacade.java:196)
>       at com.wyk.pmsys.controller.CodeController.getCode(CodeController.java:107)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

in servlet jsp convert to java used "out.write()",is this confilct with my code for "resp.getOutputStream()"? 
that's all ,how to solve it;
if something else,what's that ? and how to solve it?

Comment: The problem is your jsp is already written to the output stream. Your controller method needs to set content type to jpeg and only return the image

Comment: i have already set content type like this resp.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");  
        resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");  
        resp.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);  
        resp.setContentType("image/jpeg");

Comment: how return the image don't use response.getOutputStream()?,the question is if i use the  response.getOutputStream() in my controller it will get an error in my code.so i can't write image to jsp.

Comment: You need to separate the two requests. One for the jsp, one for the image.

Comment: yes there is two controller the one is "to jsp" and the other one  "to write image",sorry i'm not post complete code in "controller(Verification code):"

Answer (score 0):

All you need is annotation `ResponseBody` for the method:

```
@RequestMapping("/code")
@ResponseBody //<---- here
public void getCode(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)  
        throws IOException {
```

Comment: <img src=""> it's not an ajax request,and i do what you say ,still the same problem